# A “NullPointerException” could be thrown; “getBody” can return null Sonar

Tags: java, rest, sonarqube, sonarlint

Sonar points that `A "NullPointerException" could be thrown; "getBody()" can return null` around `recaptchaResponseEntity.getBody()`

```
public BooleanResponse verifyCaptcha(String recaptchaResponse) {

//Alot more sophisticated logic

    Boolean success = (Boolean) recaptchaResponseEntity.getBody().get("success");

    List<String> errors = (List) recaptchaResponseEntity.getBody().get("error-codes");
    return success ? BooleanResponse.success() : BooleanResponse.failure(errors.get(0));
  }
```

I tried

```
recaptchaResponseEntity.getBody()!=null , Objects.noNull(recaptchaResponseEntity.getBody()),
!Objects.isNull(recaptchaResponseEntity.getBody())
```

But got no luck, can you please help to resolve this issue? Thanks

Comment: What line is SonarQube reporting the issue on?  Are you replacing all the dereferences of "recaptchaResponseEntity.getBody()"?  You're not showing this.

Comment: have you tried to use `Objects.requireNonNull` method?

Answer (score 1):

Each of your example attempt do not store the compared value anywhere. I assume that you have run those checks, but then you still called `getBody()` again, which would trigger the issue (there is no guarantee that the method will return the same result twice). I would try to store `getBody()` return value in a variable and only use that after the check, e.g.:

```
<appropriate type here> recaptchaResponseBody = recaptchaResponseEntity.getBody();
if (recaptchaResponseBody != null) {
    Boolean success = (Boolean) recaptchaResponseBody.get("success");
    ...
}
```